# Update AsyncPipe when ChangeDetectorRef is detached

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

By looking at [the way change detection is implemented](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L137) in `AsyncPipe`, it seems like `this._ref.markForCheck()` doesn't run if `ChangeDetectorRef` is detached (as is also confirmed in [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7311#issuecomment-189292079)).

The motivation for this is to have full control over when the change detection occurs (by using `Observable` exclusively - alike MVVM pattern). I'm working a very performance-sensitive code where I have full control over inputs but using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` fires change detection not just for input changes but also control event fires (like click events), which degrades the performance greatly by re-running unwanted change detection sweep on every click.

So I opted to detach `ChangeDetectorRef` completely but then now the `AsyncPipe` stops working.

Is this expected behavior for `AsyncPipe`? And if so, is there a way to work around this? Or perhaps, a way to make `ChangeDetectorStrategy.OnPush` to not fire on control event fires?

---

**EDIT:**
Here is a contrived example that illustrates what I meant to do:

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <button (click)="incrementEvent.next()">Increment</button>
  <button (click)="decrementEvent.next()">Decrement</button>
  <h2>Counter: {{ counterObservable | async }}</h2>
  <!-- This should only run once but it runs on every click instead -->
  <h2>Number of atoms in universe: {{ getNumberOfAtomsInUniverse() }}</h2>
`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent {
  incrementEvent = new Subject<void>();
  decrementEvent = new Subject<void>();

  counterObservable: Observable<number>;

  constructor() {
    this.counterObservable = Observable.merge(
      this.incrementEvent.map(() => 1),
      this.decrementEvent.map(() => -1)
    )
      .startWith(0)
      .pairwise()
      .map(tup => tup[0] + tup[1])
  }

  getNumberOfAtomsInUniverse() {
    // very expensive operation...
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can attach cdRef, call `detectChanges()` and detach again

Comment: The fact you have a CD sweep on every event is logical. AFAIK, this doesn't mean however that every component itself is checked.
Let's say you have a click event. What will happen is, the CD sweep is triggered, it will see a component with CD.onPush, it will check it's inputs and it will skip this component (and subtree) if nothing has changed. So the fact a new cycle is started at every event doesn't mean everything in your component has changed. So with the proper onPush strategy on the correct places in your comp tree should not influence performance to much.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but that would require custom implementation of `AsyncPipe` with those changes no?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're doing. Perhaps adding some code that allows to reproduce (ideally also a Plunker) would be a good idea.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The part that runs repeatedly is a function call inside the template, which is impure so cannot be cached. So the only way (that I can think of) is to control the change detection instead.

Comment: @KwintenP My case is where the change detection itself is triggered **inside** the given component template via click event. So unless I'm wrong on this, it triggers change detection for the given component?

Comment: One option would be to put this: '  <h2>Number of atoms in universe: {{ getNumberOfAtomsInUniverse() }}</h2>' into a separate dumb component. You could have the CD strategy set to onPush for that one and pass a dummy input variable to the component. Every time you do want to update this component, you could change that input variable. This will trigger the dumb component to be checked and updated. 
The only disadvantage is if the user clicks on that <h2> tag :).

Comment: In this specific case I guess you could compute `getNumberOfAtomsInUniverse()` once in the code (not the template), assign it to a variable, and reference that variable in your template.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good discussion here regarding this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12356

> ...calling detach() on ChangeDetectorRef means: don't run change detection (check bindings, process child components etc.) in a template of a given component. In practice this means that data might change but the affected bindings will not be re-evaluated (this is what change detection does, after all...).

So in the example `{{ counterObservable | async }}`. If you detach change detector this will never evaluate the binding and the async pipe will never run.

I thought maybe then we could detach after the first change detection cycle, so the async pipe has been consumed, but it still doesn't update subsequent async events. It seems for now there is no way around this.

The options are either manually running `detectChanges()` or updating the dom directly.